# VMware Fusion - How to SSH into a VM when not on a network?

Tags: ssh, macos, vmware-fusion

So I have a MacBook Pro here running Mavericks and VMWare Fusion 6.

I have an Ubuntu Server VM I need for a project running. It snags a static IP on the network.

Now I like to completely ignore / hide the VM window itself and instead SSH into the machine using Terminal. On Windows I could do this with VMware Workstation without issue using PuTTy. I didn't even have to have a window open.

On the Mac, well it's a laptop to be fair and laptops go places, places without WiFi on occasion.

So how can I SSH into a VM running locally without being on any external network?

EDIT: After switching the VM to NAT, this is my ifconfig:

[image]

Comment: Could you find a solution? I am having the same problem with `VMWare Fusion 8` and `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`, I have chosen `NAT` networking but can't ssh to my machine from Mac OS X. I verified that the `ssh` daemon is running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would set the networking mode of the VM to NAT in `Virtual Machine` => `Network`.

[image]

Then reboot or reinitialize the network in the virtual machine.

From there, you can use the NAT address of the virtual machine from your Mac.
The `ifconfig` command in your VM will reveal the NAT'ed address you could use for communication between the systems.

Comment: Hello ewwhite, I don't see anything different in the ifconfig. Perhaps by setting a static IP I screwed this up?

Also how'd you screen capture that menu like that?

Comment: @CodySmith Yes, you want your VM to have a DHCP address assignment. The screenshot is captured using `Command+Shift+4`.